# I am running Python with Couchdb. From Python, how do I invoke a View I have created in Couchdb?

Tags: python, rest, couchdb

I am running Python with CouchDB. From my Python app and via a REST API, how do I invoke a View I have created in CouchDB?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I don't need to use a View to display data from CouchDB. All I have to do is the following:

```
couch = couchdb.Server('http://adm:pass@localhost:15984')
db = couch.create('countries')
doc = {'country': 'Taiwan'}
db.save(doc)

for id in db:
  print(db.get(id))
```

This will give me the following output:

```
<Document 'bf70258030d67578853a43fc010026b3'@'1-   
e84aa329b7e25dc01a38ab1a8fbfa056' {'Country': 'Taiwan'}>
```